# How do I add a corner radius and a drop shadow to a UIImageView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, shadow, cornerradius

I'd like to add a corner radius and a drop shadow to a `UIImageView` in Swift. I don't know how to do that because when adding the corner radius, I either have to set `clipsToBounds` or `masksToBounds` to true. As a consequence, I am not able to draw a shadow.

Comment: I don’t think this is a duplicate. This refers to UIImageViews. If I don’t set clipsToBounds or masksToBounds, my image won’t have rounded corners. @rbaldwin

Comment: UIView has a layer property that has a contents property on it that you can use to set images. You can then round the corners of the layer.

Comment: Hmm, thanks. Could you show an example? @LanceSamaria